# I have a small painting with a signature and seal which i cannot read.?

Tags: characters, character-identification

The painting is of a dragon on a vase.It is approximately 4 inches square  and would be interested in knowing  more about it.

[image]

Comment: Could you upload a photo of the vase?

Comment: I know that the first two characters has to be 青花. But the third character looks like it's scripted.

Comment: That's 青花「汝」, where 「汝」 points to 「汝窯」 ([*Ru* ware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ru_ware)), so it's not a signature. The seal might say  「月民」, but I don't know what it's supposed to mean - it might be some sort of name?

Comment: 青花 is the Chinese name for the famous Ming Dynasty "Blue & White" porcelain. 汝 means "porcelain ware" So, 青花汝 means Blue & White Porcelain ware. This is a painting of a blue & white porcelain vase

Comment: BTW, the painting of the dragon on the vase has "Five Claws" In the Yuan dynasty, the two-horned, five-clawed dragon was designated for use by the Son of Heaven or Emperor only, while the four-clawed dragon was used by the princes and nobles. Similarly, during the Ming and Qing dynasty, the five-clawed dragon was strictly reserved for use by the Emperor only. Pity this is only a painting and not a real vase which would be worth 100s of 1000s in an auction.